# Encrypted vs unencrypted digital signatures

Tags: encryption, hash

Is there a difference in terms of security between

1. An encrypted stream of bits obtained by encrypting a plaintext concatenated with it's signature

   $ C = E_k(plaintext||\sigma)$

   where $E$ is a symmetric or asymmetric encryption function, II is a concatenation operator and

   $\sigma=h(plaintext)^k$

   where $h$ is a secure MAC (the key is assumed to be the same).
2. A bit stream obtained by concatenating a ciphertext and the signature over the its corresponding plaintext

   $C=E_k(plaintext)||\sigma$

   where

   $\sigma=h(plaintext)^k$
3. A stream obtained by encrypting the ciphertext of the plaintext concatenated with the signature over the respective ciphertext

   $C=E_k(E_k(plaintext)||\sigma)$

   where

   $\sigma=h(E_k(plaintext))^k$

Also, is there any risk due to using the same key for both encrypting and signing? I don't refer to the cases that do not involve recovering the key through other means other than passive or active attacks.

Comment: Are you talking about MACs or asymmetric signatures? If the latter, which algorithm? And which assumptions do you make about the encryption algorithm?

Comment: Asymmetric, RSA. The encryption algorithm can be either symmetric or asymmetric The assumptions are ciphertext indistinguishability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability

Comment: And what assumptions do you make about $h^k$? Is it a secure MAC/PRF? If so, you should call it like that, and not call it hash, since without qualification that generally means an unkeyed hash.

Comment: But why? The attacker only sees the ciphertext. Any alteration of it will change bits in the signature making it invalid. Yes, $h^k$ is assumed to be a secure MAC.

Comment: The duplicate discusses the difference between your three constructions, assuming different keys are used for encryption and MAC. For the same-key question, see [Why can't I use the same key for encryption and MAC?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37880/why-cant-i-use-the-same-key-for-encryption-and-mac) on security.se.